# get_template_directory_url() not working on any page but index.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently trying to convert a html website to a WordPress website; currently having an issue with the `get_template_directory_url()` function, which will work on the index.php page but for some reason gives a fatal error on the other .php pages.

This is the code:

`<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

This is the error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_template_directory_uri() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\EdinsVerbouw\projecten.php:35
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\EdinsVerbouw\projecten.php</b> on line <b>35</b><br />
```

Comment: Are you sure the `wp-functions.php` file is included or?

Comment: @MihailMinkov Yes, it's a sample functions.php file from a wordpress theme boilerplate

Comment: Well, the thing is that Wordpress always uses `index.php` as the base file, and afterwards includes everything. Do your permalinks work fine or is there any issue with your .htaccess file?

Comment: That's what I mean, your main Wordpress file is `index.php` everything else comes through there and everything is loaded through there, so if you try to open something internal you'll get this type of errors. What is the URL you're trying to access?

Comment: @MihailMinkov it's another .php page in the same directory

Comment: @MihailMinkov and when I go to the page it crashes, if the code mentioned is included; if I remove that line of code the page loads;

Comment: @MihailMinkov tried using related functions as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, taking as base my comments above and from what I perceive you're trying to do, I think you are missing the point here. As I explained before, your main Wordpress file is `/index.php`. What does that mean?

It means that when you open:

- yourwordpresssite.com/
- yourwordpresssite.com/about
- yourwordpresssite.com/contact

Each one of these calls goes to `/index.php` with certain parameters like the name of the section or some other URL parameter. How this works can be configured via `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` in your Wordpress admin.

If you try to open something like

- yourwordpresssite.com/testfile.php

This is a completely independent file in which you'd have to replicate the way `/index.php` works and that's not what Wordpress is designed for.

What I think you are attempting to do is to access your theme files directly, but that doesn't work this way, you'd have to enable your theme from the admin and work accordingly.

I recommend you check the [Wordpress Documentation on Theme Development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

Comment: If I understand correctly, there's no way to simply link the pages (as would be done with a regular html structure) within the (theme) directory? There should be a theme folder for every (sub)page?

Comment: No, what you must do is prepare different types of templates for different types of posts, be it a posts template, a single post template a page template, etc. And then in your Wordpress admin you just create the page using the theme's template. It's designed to make reusable templates for different use cases, you don't do your menu in your theme unless you want it to be fixed for that particular site and not replicable. You can do that, but your pages and everything else has to be created in Wordpress.

Comment: Then I know what I have to do; lots of thanks for your time :) appreciate it

Comment: You can accept the answer or upvote it if it works for you :)

Comment: I did, what eventually worked was simply reading the whole file hierarchy of WordPress and found out what files are looked for by the engine (changed projecten.php to page-projecten.php and used echo get_site_url() 'path/to/file/file.php' which fixed this) but got a better understanding of wp in general

Comment: Glad you could solve it, Wordpress can be a pain in the ass :D